# Linear Bounded Automaton that accepts all strings

Tags: turing-machines, automata, undecidability

I'm currently reading Sipser's Introduction to the Theory of Computation, and I'm reading up about linear bounded automata, now we know from Rice's Theorem that whether a TM can accept all strings in a given alphabet is undecidable, I was wondering if the same could apply to linear bounded automata, if not, how would one go about proving the undecidability of such a problem (or its decidabilty?). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For Turing machines another problem is also undecidable: whether it accepts any string at all. This is already undecidable for LBA. Basically the proof is by oberving that we can replace a TM accepting string $w$ by a LBA accepting the `trace of the computation' by the TM on $w$. The verification of the trace of the computation does not need more space than the computation itself, and thus can be verified by a LBA.

The question whether a device accepts *all* strings is already undecidable on a lower level of the Chomsky hierarchy, the context-free languages (CF grammars,or pushdown automata).

Comment: But could I prove this undecidability of an LBA accepting all strings using a reduction from the acceptance problem of a TM for example?

Comment: This can probably be done. Just make sure that all strings that do not code `traces of computations' of the original TM are accepted by the LBA. Returning on what I said, the non-computations together with the non-accepting computations are actually context-free.